# Search Users with Ruby Variable as Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a simple search functionality within my app. To do this, the user will search on the page "/search/users/[query]". The parameters are setup correctly, but I cannot figure how to make it so that it searches the database for all users that the search term is in their username. I feel like I'm almost there, but it does not work:

```
   def search_handler
        @query = params[:query]
        @type = params[:type]
        if @type == "users"
          @users = User.all.username.match(@query/i)
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try passing the `params[:query]` to a `LIKE` SQL query within a `where` ActiveRecord statement:

```
def search_handler
  @query = params[:query]
  @type  = params[:type]
  if @type == 'users'
    @users = User.where('username LIKE ?', "%#{@query}%")
  end
end
```

That will give you all the users where the username matches with the value of `@query` you've passed, producing an SQL query like:

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (username LIKE '%blablabla%') LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

You could take a look to the [`ActiveRecord Query Methods`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) for improving your queries in Rails.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Note that `LIKE` may or may not be case sensitive depending on the database you're using so you'll probably want to downcase the column value and pattern if you want a case insensitive search.